# Initializing auto variables in VC++ 2012

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am new to VC++ 2012. I have this code snippet.

```
auto it = query_map.find(U("callback"));
```

The problem is right under the dot there is a red line the error is

```
Error 1 error C2664: 'std::_Tree_iterator std::_Tree::find(const http::uri::encoded_string &)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const wchar_t [9]' to 'const http::uri::encoded_string &' d:\maverick\projects\strikeforce\src\server\server\server.cpp 26
```

Can someone tell me a solution to this error?

Comment: Read the error again message, it tells you exactly what is wrong.

Comment: Try removing the "auto it = " and you'll get the same error.

Answer (score 2):

```
Error 1 error C2664: 'std::_Tree_iterator std::_Tree::find(const http::uri::encoded_string &)'
```

This is a problem with the method find() from the class std::Tree

```
cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const wchar_t [9]' to 'const http::uri::encoded_string &'
```

The find() method must be used with a paremeter of type `'const http::uri::encoded_string &'`, but you passed a `'const wchar_t [9]'`.

the method `U()` you have used returns an array of chars, but the `find()` method need another type of object.